# Need to create a matrix with specific elements using only one command

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I need to create the following matrix using **only a single command** without typing it out explicitly:

```
M = [0 0 0 0 0 0;...
     0 0 0 0 0 0;...
     0 0 0 0 0 0;...
     0 0 0 1 2 3;...
     0 0 0 4 5 6;....
     0 0 0 7 8 9]
```

I'm new at this so I can't use any complicated commands.

I tried to use `linspace` combined with `zeros` but it didn't work out very well.

Please help!!

Comment: What is the basis of this requirement?

Comment: by single command do you mean a single line?

Comment: I'll +1 this question if a motivation would be provided: why is this "single command" requirement?

Answer (score 10):

If the matrix `M` is not defined yet, you may skip the `zeros(6)` (proposed by [AlexL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14350228/1714410)) and go straight to

```
M( 4:6, 4:6 ) = reshape( 1:9, [3 3] ).'; %'
```

Answer (score 6):

Is that using too complicated commands?

```
ans=padarray(reshape(1:9,3,3)',[3 3],'pre')
```

Comment: elegant or not, in my view your answer is better... (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about Matlab, but in Octave, you can do:

```
M = [zeros(3, 6); zeros(3), [1:3; 4:6; 7:9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another easy and compact oneliner, combining some of the things already mentioned for MATLAB and Octave:

```
M(4:6,4:6) = [1:3;4:6;7:9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try creating a 6x6 matrix full of [zeros](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html):

```
M = zeros(6)
```

Then just setting part of it to [1:9](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)?

```
M(4:6,4:6) = reshape(1:9, 3, 3)'
```

(The ' symbol means transpose)

Comment: (This is untested, so I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me if this doesn't work)

Comment: My MatLab complains about the dimension mismatch.  I do: `M(4:6,4:6) = transpose(reshape(1:9, 3, 3))`.  But that might come under 'complicated commands'.

Comment: Thanks @paddy, reshaping then transposing it should do the trick.

Comment: Assuming `M` is undefined, you may discard the first line of `M = zeros(6);`. Then you have a **single command** solution, as required.

Comment: @Shai I interpreted "one command" as "a simple solution" (I ignore silly requirements, my boss hates me)

Answer (score 0):

Correcting Alex's answer:

```
M = zeros(6)

M(4:6,4:6) = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? This is not exactly a single command solution...